# dynamic height page but div height not working

Tags: html, css

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
```

}

```
#nav-left {
width: 155px;
min-height: 100%;
background-color: #292a28;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
```

}

When on my page, height growing up (dynamic), my height on div did not growing up.[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkAvn.png)

Comment: add height #nav-left -  height 100%

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
html, body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#nav-left {
  width: 155px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #292a28;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Working example: http://liveweave.com/9gb8mF